# ASP.NET: The value 'x' is not valid for id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Withing my application, on all Edit commands for all models, I get the error stated in the title. There is a progressive elimination of factors I have been posting on the asp.net forums, which I will exclude here for brevity: http://forums.asp.net/p/1879643/5291012.aspx/1?Re+Model+foreign+key+defaulting+to+0+in+edit+operation

If you check the above link, you can verify my analysis.

My foreign key bindings are legitimate, so I am wondering as to if this problem is more deeply rooted.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please ask the current problem you are having with all details here (not just a link). Your question is likely just to get closed otherwise.